# Component used by another module without exporting

Tags: angular

From the definition I found that an Angular module can import another module and then can use those components which are exported in that module. For example, I have an `app` module and a `shared` module. I have imported the `shared` module in `app` module. `shared` module has a component named `log` component. I can use that component inside the `app` module. But `shared` module did not export the `log` component.

[image: project structure]

app module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { LogComponent } from './shared/log.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        SharedModule
    ],
    bootstrap: [LogComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

shared module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { LogComponent } from './log.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
        declarations: [
        LogComponent
    ]/*,
    exports: [
        LogComponent
    ]*/
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

log component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-log',
    templateUrl: './log.component.html'
})
export class LogComponent {
    title: string = "this is log component";
}
```

log html

```
<p>
    {{title}}
</p>
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ModuleDemo</title>
    <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
    <app-log></app-log>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: output]

Can anyone clear this, why without importing the `log` component `app` module can use that.

Comment: You're bootstrapping the log component instead of bootstrapping the AppComponent. And your HTML displays the log component instead of displaying the app component.

Comment: @JBNizet Why not make an answer?

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for your comment. This is the answer of my question.